# Is this a php variable variable bug?

Tags: php, variables

Is there a logical explanation to this?

```
<?php  
$$a = 'hello world';  
echo $$a; //displays hello world  
echo $$aa; //displays hello world  
echo $$aaa; //displays hello world  
?>
```

Comment: This is probably a php 5.3 behaviour

Comment: No it is not, he is not getting it right.

Comment: Thanks all. This makes sense now, in other words.

echo ${null};

is valid as well.

Comment: No. Its not valid. But it works. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you try

```
$$a = 'hello world';
echo $$a; //displays hello world
echo $$aa; //displays hello world
echo $$aaa; //displays hello world


die( "<pre>" . print_r( get_defined_vars(), true ) . "</pre>" );
```

You can see that it has registed a variable with no name so yes, according to PHP's naming conventions, this would be a bug

Comment: so contrary to php naming convention, a variable can be null, or an empty string

Comment: I think he refers to the naming conventions for the variable name itself. `$var` is a variable, but `$` isn't...

Comment: I'm not sure what makes this a bug. It's definitely not good practice, and I wish PHP would raise warnings on things like this by default, but the behavior is consistent.

Answer (score 12):

When doing

```
$$a = 'foo';
```

you are saying take the value of `$a`. Convert it to string. Use the String as variable name to assign `'foo'` to it. Since `$a` is undefined and returns `NULL`, which when typecasted to String is `''`, you are assigning the variable `${''}`;

```
echo ${''}; // 'foo'
```

Ironically, you can do

```
${''} = 'foo'; /* but not */ $ = 'foo';
```

And you can do

```
${''} = function() { return func_get_arg(0); };
echo ${''}('Hello World');
// or
echo $$x('Hello World');
```

which would trigger a notice about `$x` being undefined but output `Hello World` then. Funny enough, the following doesnt work:

```
${''} = function() { return func_get_arg(0); };
echo $x('Hello World');
```

Because it triggers *Fatal error: Function name must be a string*. Quirky :D

Since the PHP manual says

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

I'd consider being able to assign an empty named variable a bug indeed.

There is a somewhat related bug filed for this already:

- http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39150

Comment: Not sure if that's irony, isn't that exactly what you would expect? Doesn't that speak more to how the parser is functioning, in that it only recognizes explicit declarations of an empty string. Disclaimer: I know nothing about php.

Comment: @Grantismo I'd expect PHP to prevent me from doing ${''} = 'foo' when I cannot do $ = 'foo' either and the manual states that variables must have a name. Also, the common way of assigning variables is without the curly braces. But yeah, makes you wonder about the parser :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting that it's defining the variable as something to the effect of `${''}`, or a variable with no name, or something along those lines.

Since neither `$a` nor `$aa` nor `$aaa` are defined, they all point to the same funky, blank variable name when used in a variable variable context.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $a is empty, then you're setting an empty variable name to = 'hello world'...  So then every time you reference that empty variable name, you'll get what's stored there...

It's just like

```
$a = '';
$$a = 'Foo Bar';
$b = '';
echo $$b; //Displays Foo Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting it right, consider this:

```
$a = 'hello';
$hello = "hello again";
echo $$a;
```

**Output:**

```
hello again
```

In your case, you have not set the value of following variables, so it outputs the same.

**Explanation:**

When you do `$$a`, it means:

```
$                           $a;
^                            ^
$ used for php vars         means a's value that is hello
```

So it becomes:

```
$hello
```

Whose value is:

```
hello again
```

Comment: I understand variable variable, I am just amused that there can be an unnamed variable, or a variable with null or an empty string set as its name.